# asp.net : how to exchange informations with javascript?

Tags: asp.net

I want to use the input box at the users' computer (javascript) and send the information to the host computer(asp) by `windows.location.href="http://XX.XX.XX.XX"`. I want to use something like `http://XX.XX.XX.XX/username=.......&password=.....` but it's not safe.

I hope not use AJAX.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are using to send this information is the GET protocol.
To send it not through the URL you need to use POST. Click [Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/difference-between-get-and-post1) to see the difference. You can google on how to implement this yourself.

Comment: Thanks , I have already done it . The imformation is really useful .

Comment: @zhuchengyang If this is the correct answer, could you please mark it as such.

Comment: "POST" really isn't any safer than "GET" ... unless you're using HTTPS

Comment: It is safer. GET puts the information through the URL so anything that records the URL can get the password. Also, GET requests can be forced. While, POST isn't 100% safe - nothing is. It's the best alternative even if it's not encrypted through HTTP. Obviously, like you said, this isn't an issue with HTTPS.